# Excel VBA Cell to read text box contents based upon the location of the textbox (textbox will be moved to above the cell)

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently creating a cause tree analysis form that needs to be uploaded into a Saas platform from excel. The SaaS platform can only read cells and not text boxes.

**Process.**

1. List out text in text boxes as necessary could be 80 text boxes.
2. move text boxes to the necessary location around the sheet.
3. Cell if at all possible, reads the text box which is placed above the cell.
4. uploaded to SaaS application.

Here is an example of the sheet:

[image]

I can create a VBA to read specific cells but cannot create one that is dynamic enough to read text boxes based upon their location within the excel.

Comment: Why do you use textboxes - why not enter the values to the cell?

Comment: @Ike perhaps because the application is a questionaire with multiple answers that can be selected and moved into the correct place as text boxes.

Comment: @Ike All the text boxes are predefined and then moved to the location. If it did not work this way all our end users would have to copy and paste whats in the text box into the correct cell. And then that cell could change if new information is added. You could end up shifting text in 9 cells to the left to insert one new one.

Comment: Not sure if I understand: Is this a userform or is this an artfully designed sheet? If it is a sheet: Are those ActiveX textboxes, Form controls or shapes?

Comment: Shapes on a worksheet have a `TopLeftCell` property which can be used to find the cell directly under the top left corner of the shape.   You'll need to loop over the shapes on the sheet and compare that to the cells you need to find a shape for (or just compare the cell's Top and Left properties with each shape on the sheet)

Comment: In ChatGPT try asking "In Excel VBA how can I find which shape is positioned over a specific cell"  That looks like a good starting point.

Comment: @FunThomas This is an artfully designed sheet. They are not Active X Textboxes. Text box added from shapes

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to simply copy the values of the textboxes, for example like this. The property `TopLeftCell` is of Type Range and points directly to a cell.

```
Sub CopyShapeText()
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes  ' <-- Maybe you need to change that
        If sh.Type = msoTextBox Then
            sh.TopLeftCell.Value = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If you don't want that the text is visible in the sheet, simply set the font color to white.

Drawback is that you need to call this routine once the user is done with the input. With other words: The step 3 is not executed automatically, you need to call the routine before step 4 is executed.

I have researched, but there is no *linked cell* property for a shape (as it is for some controls you can put on a sheet), and there are no triggers available for shapes that could copy the text whenever a cell text is modified.